# Heroku partially not serving some of my images, anyone faced this issue before?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am using node js and express server to serve my html and assets, all of it is under a public folder. Everything is being served right using 
`app.use(express.static("./public"));`
except 3 images which are returning 404, strange thing is that other images are fine. I have tried almost everything from changing paths, restarting heroku with no luck.(works fine locally btw)

Comment: Have you tried using `app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: yep, for some reason heroku was not taking JPG only jpg as extensions

Answer (score 0):

Well found that heroku was not taking JPG extensions on my case. Only lowercase jpg extension.